# Python libraries, packages, modules

Tags: python, module, package, libraries

How do I know that a library, package or module exists (standard and external) that I could use to solve a given problem? For example, I have used the BeautifulSoup library to "decode" a web site while looking up some beginner practices, but I only knew BeautifulSoup exists because I saw it in a practice example and would have never known of it's existence if I didn't stumble upon it.

Comment: just try to import the module, and run, if the code runs smoothly, then module exists in your environment. Is this you are looking?

Comment: You are answering your question here: "I only knew BeautifulSoup exists because I saw it in a practice example". Practice is what you need. When you are facing some kind of problem, you go googling libraries that can solve your problem.

Comment: This is one more point where you miss things like the R equivalent of task view in Python. Nonetheless PyPI does have a search facility on many parameters. You might look up for topic-wise categorization. Or simply search for a phrase like "scraping". This most of the time works out ok, but nowhere nearly as neat as the CRAN task view.

Comment: Have you installed it with `pip`?

Comment: No, I just instaled it in pycharm and upgraded it with cmd.

Comment: It is good practice to use `pip`. Do you have `pip` installed? (If you don't know, go to your terminal and type pip)

Comment: I do have pip, but I why does it matter if I install over pip or over  pycharm?

Answer (score 0):

#### All libraries in Python are managed by the "Pip Installs Packages" package manager (pip)

(For more infos please refer to the [Python 3.7.2 documentation — Installing Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html))

Every module/lib installed in your local Python system can be listed using the [`pip freeze`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/#pip-freeze) command in your system.

Comment: Ok, but the names of the modules don't give away their nature (for what they are good for). The library/module name, e. g. BeautifulSoup, means nothing intuitively and I could never guess that there is a library with that exact name and use. Do python programers  just memorize the names and uses of the modules they stumble upon during their carreer or is there a method to this madness?

Comment: Yes there is a good method, like for all language and development environment, [Google](https://www.google.com) the name and find the library's documentation ([Beautiful Soup Documentation — Beautiful Soup 4.4.0 documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/))
You can reverse the process to find a library that does what you want by searching for basic terms followed by "Python"

Comment: By "exists" you should have been more specific on your first question. Talking about the lib's existance in your system **or** talking about the fact that a lib exists that does what you want